WriteConsoleOutputCharacter not working properly
I was trying to set a couple functions to work with the windows console. The function WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() from the Window API is not printing the full string like it used to, at first i thought it was the way i was doing it, but then i tried to do it out of the function on a new file, and i get the same result:
The code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int main() {
    HANDLE console = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(console);
    wchar_t* data = L"Hello World";
    DWORD bytes = 0;
    COORD pos = {0,0};

    while (1) {
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(console, data, strlen(data), pos, &bytes);
    }

    CloseHandle(console);

    return 0;
}

The output: H (the first character of the string).
It does not print when out of a loop.
NOTE:  The charset on the preprocessor definition is set to unicode.

The function strlen should only be used on single-byte character strings, and not on UTF-16 (which Microsoft refers to as "Unicode" or "wide") strings. Since you are using a UTF-16 string, you should be using the function wcslen instead.
The function call strlen( L"Hello World" ); will return 1, which is not what you want. It will return 1 because the UTF-16 letter H is encoded with the byte values 72 followed by 0, and strlen will return the position of the first byte with the value 0 that it finds.

It worked, Thank you a lot! It's good to know about that difference.

Weird that he didn't get a compiler error. Calling strlen with wchar_t* shouldn't compile

@MichaelChourdakis: On Microsoft Visual Studio, I get a warning, not an error, when compiling OP's code. My guess is that OP did, too, but ignored it. However, I am not sure, as I don't know which compiler OP is using.

Also an error wchar_t* data = L"Hello World"; Should be const. What C++ version is used?
